Why is the object causing curiosity the subject on the verb 궁금하다
In sentences like:

나는 그 수수께끼의 답이 너무 궁금하다. (I'm very curious about the answer to that riddle.)
그녀는 그가 여기에 온 이유가 궁금했다. (She was curious about why he had come here.)

The subject of the verb is the object generating the curiosity, so it feels weird that the definition of 궁금하다 is 'to be curious' (Having a strong desire to know about something.) as the way I see it it'd be more of 'to generate or cause curiosity'.

The full explanation might be somewhat involved, so I'll give you the simple answer first, namely: [NOUN]-이/가 궁금하다 is an idiomatic expression.  We very rarely say -에 대해서/관해서 궁금하다, even though -에 대해서 or -에 관해서 (both means "about" or "as to") is what we normally use for verbs such as 말하다, 논의하다, 토론하다 and so on.
Going into more details, 궁금하다 is a case of the pattern known as "emotion expressions" which is class of adjectives and their verb variants expressing gut reaction-like sentiments.  These expressions can take different forms depending on the grammatical person (since you can't know other peoples' mind as you do yours):

For the 1st person, you use adjective expression => (나는) 답이 궁금하다.
For the 3rd person, you use verb expression => (친구는) 답을 궁금해한다.
(note the 이 vs 을, since one is subjective and the other is objective case)

Your sentences are both the first case (see note below for why), as they use -이/가 궁금하다 form.

나는 [답]이 너무 궁금하다 = I am so curious about [the answer].

This "나는 N-이/가 [adjective]" is what you might call two-tiered sentence (or doubly-subjected sometimes) because both 나 and N here function as a subject. 는 serves as the sentence level subject (or topic) and N is the detail  clause's subject.  The meaning is similar to "As for me (나), the answer (답) is curious/fascinating", except that in the Korean version the adjective applies to both subjects equally.  So we can say 나는 답이 궁금해요, 나는 궁금해요 and 답이 궁금해요 equally naturally.
This is just how Korean has developed and there is no direct analogue in English.
It is a widely used grammar structure.  Here are some examples.

나는 저 사람이 싫어 (vs 동생은 저 사람을 싫어한다) = As for me, that person is unlikable = I don't like that person (vs My brother doesn't like that person).
나는 네가 부끄러워 (vs 친구는 자기 동생을 부끄러워한다) = As for me, you are shameful = I am ashamed of you (vs. My friend is ashamed of his brother).

[Final Note]
Your second example 그녀는 그가 여기에 온 이유가 궁금했다 is about 그녀, a 3rd person, but it's using the adjective expression 이유가 궁금했다 instead of the verb expression 이유를 궁금해했다.  Why is this?
The reason behind it is the context.  The adjective vs verb rule exists to disambiguate confusing cases where the expression can possibly apply to both the speaker and someone else.  For example, without it 그 사람이 싫어 can be ambiguous -- does it mean I don't like him, or he doesn't like something?
In situations where such ambiguity cannot occur at all, you use the adjective expression (which is more direct and effective) even for the third person.  So the example sentence is what you would use in a novel or a drama narration (since you know the writer/narrator is not going to say anything personal), not something you'd encounter in real life.  This is a point that gets very subtle but native-level speakers catch such nuances instinctively.

Thanks for the long explanation. I knew about the structure 나는 N-이/가 [adjective], it's just that for cases like 나는 축구가 좋아 vs 나는 축구를 좋아해, for me the difference is obvious and works, because it is "As for me, football is good" vs "I like football", which in a sense is the same thing, just using topic + subject + descriptive verb / intransitive vs subject + object + transitive verb, but what I couldn't understand about this same case for 궁금하다 is that being curious can mean both being the agent feeling curiosity about something and also being the thing generating curiosity to some external agent.

In a sense you're correct: if you take the Korean sentence and keep the subject as subject in the corresponding English sentence, then 궁금하다 cannot be "is curious."

[그 수수께끼의 답]이 궁금하다
=> [The answer of the riddle] is curious.  (X)
=> [The answer of the riddle] is the subject of my curiosity.  (OK?)

However, the obvious problem is that no English speaker says something like "The answer of the riddle is the subject of my curiosity" unless they want to sound really pretentious.  This is simply not how English speakers speak.
Hence, when we say 궁금하다 means "curious," the implicit understanding is that they don't take the same grammatical subject: 궁금하다 is the correct word to use when you want to say someone is "curious" about something, you just have to rearrange the remainder of the sentence.

The subject of the verb cannot be the object……
The subject is not generating curiosity.
In the 1st example, the riddle is generating(causing) curiosity.
In the 2nd example, the woman ‘is’ curious and the man’s arrival caused her curiosity such that her curiosity was generated/caused by the man’s arrival.
